# How to fix Google Chrome Audit Best Practice show "Does not use HTTP/2 for all of its resources" while my site already have https

Tags: google-chrome

- Hosting server Godaddy
- PHP Laravel Framework
- Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Google Chrome Best Practise suggestion 
"Does not use HTTP/2 for all of its resources 31 requests not served via HTTP/2"
while my site is used https already.
[image]